# Circular grid of uniform density

Tags: c++, opengl

How can I generate a circular grid, made of tiles with uniform area/whose vertices are uniformly distributed?

I'll need to apply the Laplacian operator to the grid at each frame of my program.

Applying the Laplacian was easy with a rectangular grid made of rectangular tiles whose locations were specified in cartesian coordinates, since for a tile at (i,j), I knew the positions of its neighboring tiles to be (i-1,j), (i,j-1), (i+1,j), and (i,j+1).

While I'd like to use polar coordinates, I'm not sure whether querying a tile's neighborhood would be as easy.

I'm working in OpenGl, and could either render triangles or points. Triangles seem more efficient (and have the nice effect of filling the area between their vertices), but seem more amenable to cartesian coordinates. Perhaps I could render points and then polar coordinates would work fine?

The other concern is the density of tiles. I want waves traveling on the surface of this mesh to have the same resolution whether they're at the center or not.

So the two main concerns are: generating the mesh in a way that allows for easy querying of a tiles' neighborhood, and in a way that preserves a uniform density distribution of tiles.

Comment: What is a "circular grid"?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're asking for something impossible.

However, [this](http://mathproofs.blogspot.co.uk/2005/07/mapping-square-to-circle.html) is a technique for remapping a regular square 2D grid into a circle shape with a relatively low amount of warping. It might suffice for your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to have a look at [this paper](http://lgdv.cs.fau.de/uploads/publications/spherical_fibonacci_mapping.pdf), it has been written to sample spheres but you might be able to adapt it for a circle.